# Handle http url with my app (if installed)

Tags: ios, objective-c, url

I would like to handle a url like: `http://www.something.com/product/3/` in this way:

- If you have the App installed => handle it with the App.
- Else => handle it with safari.

Is it this possible?

The idea is I can send that url via email and if the receiver has the app installed, then the app raises up and do something, and if not installed just open it via safari.

I know about the custom schemes, which work fine in the app but they obviously don't work in safari because they are not http protocol.

Comment: Nope, this isn't possible without jailbreaking. You could get your website to attempt a redirect to your custom scheme URL, though...

Comment: Try this: A.  Make your app handle html extension.  B.  Send email the link with a html file (the starting file or a redirection file, etc.)

Comment: @SimonM I think yours is the only solution. To use a normal link (http://something.com/product/3/) and in that web try opening a popup with the url myscheme://something.com/product/3/ which will open the app if installed or display something (probably will show google search because it doesn't understand myscheme as a web url).

Comment: @JosepBibiloni  Hi josep im my app also same requirement. if u find any solution regarding this can u post the solution.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a custom URL scheme in your app. Follow the link if you don't know how to create a custom URL scheme: http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

2) Then add following script to the URLs that you want your app to open.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var iOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);
    var appUrlScheme = "myappscheme://" + document.URL;
    if (iOS) {
        window.open(appUrlScheme, "_self");
    } 
</script>
```

The script is self explanatory, if its an iOS device then it simply tries to open current url with your custom url scheme i.e. `myappscheme://whateverurl.com'. If you app is installed on the device then iOS is going to launch your app and pass this URL to`handleOpenURL`function, otherwise mobile safari will silently ignore`window.open` call and your webpage will load as normal:

3) Implement `handleOpenURL` callback method in your AppDelegate to handle the URL:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);

   //REDIRECT USER TO A VIEW CONTROLLER

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me when the app isn't installed - I get an error saying "Cannot Open Page. Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid."

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do by using **URL Scheme**, 
First create your own custom url scheme in ***Info.plist file***

Add a new row by going to the menu and clicking Editor > Add Item. Set up a URL Types item by adding a new item. Expand the URL Types key, expand Item 0, and add a new item, “URL schemes”. Fill in “readtext” for Item 0 of “URL schemes” and your company identifier for the “URL Identifier”.

Then parse your url for different url for same url scheme to open your app with different screens.. Here i have shown only alert, use to open your specific page as per your link.. And if the app is not installed then it will open in web browser.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // Display text
    UIAlertView *alertView;
    NSString *text = [[url host] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Text" message:text delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    return YES;
}
```

*application:handleOpenURL*:    (used for earlier iOS 4.1)
 *application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:*     (used for later iOS 4.1).

Comment: What if the App is not installed? Will safari understand readtext://something.com and translate into http://something.com ?

Comment: U can use canOpenURL: to check if it can be opened or not else redirect to browser:-)..

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, because to run canOpenURL I need the app to be installed. The problem is still the same: when the app is not installed I just have an URL that safari doesn't understand (myscheme://something.com)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618254/how-to-open-an-app-if-installed-thru-a-webpage-in-safari.  It discusses how to handle if app is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible. 
However you can include in the mail both links:

- To open it in safari as normal website: http://www.somewebsite.com
- To open the app using [custom urls](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html): yourapp://