# Conditional deep link or url in email

Tags: ios, email, url

Is it possible to send an (HTML) email with links, so that if the user is reading the email in his iPhone, the links will take him to our app, but if he's reading the email in a computer, the links will open up in the browser?

Our app already has deep linking implemented. Any hacky workaround will be appreciated too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to link to a URL on your own server, which attempts to open the app if you’re on an iPhone. It requires a roundtrip through Safari, but it will work. You can have the page attempt to open the app, and if Safari is still open after 2 seconds, assume it failed and redirect to the mobile site. That redirect trick is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17618471/255489).